# I canot launch the windows

Tags: windows, ssd

A couple of days ago I bought a new computer (Desktop) with M.2 NVMe SSD which is plugged into a slot on the motherboard. My motherboard BIOS is set to UEFI. at first, it was working normally and suddenly the screen went black and I went into the BIOS, then I found out that the device does not see my 2TB SSD.  I tried restarting the computer, after several reboots, it looked like my storage was 2GB instead of 2TB.  Does anyone know what this is? Does this mean that the SSD is corrupted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's brand new, you should ask for warranty of your pc

Comment: Agreed - replace or return the computer.